Validator geronimo-validation_1.0_spec not supporting spring 3
When i am using spring boot 3.2.0 with geronimo-validation_1.0_spec  validator its not working throwing issue  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.validation.ValidationException: Could not create Configuration., But its working with spring version 2 ,, any help please ?
I tried changing the spring version but our requirement is to use spring version 3.

Spring 3.2 or Sprnig Boot 3.2? Because that makes a whole lot of difference and Spring 3.2 has been out of support for quite some years.

Spring boot 3.2.0

Spring Boot 3.2 uses JakartaEE not JavaEE. You are using an unsupported dependency which you shouldn't have in the first place. Ditch that dependency and just add spring-boot-starter-validation which includes all needed dependencies.

Thanks. Its working , but in addition to spring-boot-starter-validation we added extra 3 dependency(hibernate-validator-annotation-processor,javax.validation,jakarta.validation).It works fine . Thanks Again

You don't need those dependencies, those are already pulled in. Next to that javax.validation isn't even compatible as that is again JavaEE and not JakartaEE.

HI, The issue is , My current application is using java 17 and one expernal jar, which internally uses, e javax.xml.bind  , But in my new application i am using hibernate validator,, which is not compatible.  , And i am getting issue when open swagger and trigger rest api ,
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]. Any solution pls?

Which has nothing to do with javax.validation, in newer Java versions the XML classes have been removed from the JDK. So you need to explicitly add those.
